# Nintendo Switch Sharing

Tags: nintendo-switch

If I were to buy a game and play it on my friends switch (since I do not have a switch anymore but am trying to buy one again), is it possible to transfer that save data from my friends switch to my new switch? I think I read somewhere that I would need to be logged into a switch with my nintendo account?

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to log-in your Nintendo account at your friend's Nintendo Switch, play that game, save some data. But 3 things ware needed before :

1. Your Nintendo account should have **Nintendo  Switch Online** membership enable
2. The game you played must have **Save Data Cloud Backup** support
3. Connect Nintendo Switch to internet

After that, you can  sync your saved game to your new Nintendo Switch.

---

**UPDATE**

Here's some unofficial list of games so far that doesn't support **Save Data Cloud Backup**

[reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/nintendo/comments/9dxj8f/list_of_switch_games_so_far_that_dont_support/)
[nintendo life](http://www.nintendolife.com/news/2020/02/guide_which_nintendo_switch_games_do_not_support_cloud_saves)

Answer (score 0):

There is an option under the Settings menu found on the Home screen that is labeled Transfer Account. While I've never used it, its description says it is to transfer a user account from one Switch device to another Switch device. While you'll probably need the games in order to make any saved data work, it should allow you to move everything you've done on your friend's Switch to your own Switch when you buy a new one. Just make sure you are using your own account for everything you want to keep, because there is no way to copy an account or differentiate which games or save files within an account should get transfered.